# How to create single page of advance custom field in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am create post with advance custom field (movie-page.php) I want to create single page(single-movie.php) each post of movie-page.php when I am click on each post it link to full details but I can not do it. Help me please!!!. thanks you.

And here is my code **movie-page.php**

```
<?php
/*
 *  Template Name: Page - Movie Page
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php 

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'movie'
));

if( $posts ): ?>

    <ul>

    <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 

        setup_postdata( $post )

        ?>
<div class="jol">
            <a href="<?php get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php the_title($post->ID); ?></a>
            <?php get_post_field('descriptionii',$post->ID ); ?>
             <?php the_content() ?>
            <?php the_field("descriptionii") ?>
</div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php
/*
 *  Template Name: Page - Movie Page
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'movie',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
);
$posts_array = get_posts($args);

foreach ($posts_array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<a href=".$value->guid.">".$value->post_title."</a></br>";
    echo $value->post_content;
}
?>
<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: Otherwise create one file archive-{post_type}.php in your theme. It will display your archive page of custom post type

Comment: it's not work for me bro, when I click link to it is not go to full details.

Comment: what is archive-{post_type}.php ? or I need to create like that archive-movie.php. right ?

Comment: yes absolutely right. create archive-movie.php in your theme.

Comment: and then what code to pass into archive-movie.php ?bro

Comment: sorry bro I try hard to do it but still not work :( when I clikc link for show all details it not work

Comment: which link you had open for archive page??

Comment: Open your site_link/movie

Comment: I am still not hosting it :(

Comment: Can please tell me which type of error while using above answer code??? And are u selecting this template to related page

Comment: it is no error, I am just click it then loading in the same page

Comment: can you update full answer witch archive-movie.php ? bro

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in E:\wamp\www\cus\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen\movie-page.php on line 11

Comment: Now check it i have edited answer and let me known if you have any query

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in E:\wamp\www\cus\wp-content\themes\twentyfifteen\movie-page.php on line 11

Comment: Check it i am change some part of answer

Comment: Check letest code.......... Add html tag that you want in your template. I have print only the content you want.

Comment: Thanks br, but when I click on link it go to blank page, and I can not echo my lorem text with advance custom field the_field("descriptionii")

Comment: var_dump($posts_array) and check 'descriptionii' parameter in that var_dump value. And use that parameter. And about link if this not working then use get_permalink($value->ID) for adding link.

Comment: Ok very thansk bro I will try do it my best , very thanks :D